# How to append values to a key in a nested dict and avoid brackets

Tags: python

I have a code which formats these lines from files below into a dictionary:

```
CommonChar pins Category General

CommonChar pins Contact Mark

CommonChar pins Description This is a 

CommonChar nails Category specific

CommonChar nails Contact John 

CommonChar pins Description This is a description
```

Final dict looks like this:

```
main_dict = {
'pins':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
    },
'nails':
    {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    }}
```

I have this code today to create above dict:

```
filePath= os.path.join(dirName,eachFile)
fh=open(filePath, "r")
contents=fh.read()
items=re.findall("CommonChar.*$",contents,re.MULTILINE)
for x in items:
parts=x.split()
    if parts[1] in mainDict:
        if parts[2] in mainDict[parts[1]]:
            sys.exit("exit")
        else:
            mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]})
    else:
        mainDict[parts[1]]={}
        mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]})
```

If my input to the code changes as below, then I need to append the values of similar keys:

```
CommonChar pins Category General

CommonChar pins Contact Mark

CommonChar pins Description This is a 

CommonChar pins Description secondLine

CommonChar nails Category specific

CommonChar nails Contact John 

CommonChar pins Description This is a description
```

I need an output like this below from above lines :

```
</br>
```

being added to it as well .

```
main_dict = {
'pins':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a','</br>','secondLine']
    },
'nails':
    {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    }}
```

For that I am replacing this line:

```
sys.exit("exit")
```

with this:

```
mainDict[parts[1]][parts[2]].append(parts[3:])
```

But I get an output like this:

```
 main_dict = {
'pins':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a',['secondLine']]
    },
'nails':
    {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    }}
```

So how to avoid adding those extra [ ] to secondLine and add

```
</br>
```

infront of it?

Comment: you posted waay to much. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Use `.extend()` instead of `.append()` to fix this particular problem.

Comment: @hop extend works and how to add </br> infront of it ?

Comment: `.extend(['<br'] + other_list)`

Comment: that works smooth ....

Comment: Also, how can I capture the file location where I find the CommonChar when scanning through files?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a list of files in the directory, and some have `CommonChar` but some don't? And you want to store the names of the files that have it? Does that mean you want an outer dictionary to hold all main_dicts for each file, like this? `{'file1': {'pins': {'Category: ['General'], ...}, ...}, 'file2': {'pins': {'Category: ['General'], ...}, ...}}`

Comment: yes some files have commonChar and some dont, if I can capture the paths of those which have commonChar and store in in the existing main_dict somehow would be good.  main_dict = {
'pins':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a',['secondLine']]
   'fileLocation':['/home/usr/...'] },
'nails':
    {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    'fileLocation':['/home/usr/...'] }}

Comment: @MatthiasFripp can we do this ?

Comment: @Heyya, Yes, but what if there are multiple files covering the same topics (e.g., with the same 'group' entry as I've called it)? Would you want to combine all their data into a single dictionary for the group somehow? If so, how? Concatenate lists of 'Category' entries, lists of 'fileLocation' entries, etc.?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp scenario of multiple files covering same topics wont happen. Every file which has this CommonChar will have unique entries(pins, nails etc) in my example. This being said I need to capture file location of those files in them. main_dict = { 'pins': { 'Category': ['General'], 'Contact': ['Mark'], 'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a',['secondLine']] 'fileLocation':['/home/usr/...'] }, 'nails': { 'Category': ['specific'], 'Contact': ['Jon'], 'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description'] 'fileLocation':['/home/usr/...'] }} Does this make sense ?

Comment: @Heyya I updated my answer to store the file name, assuming each group ('pins', 'nails', etc.) only appears in one file.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Just to confirm from the output of your modified code the file location for 'nails' and 'pins' would be different right and not same(/tmp/data.txt)? Again to clarify the file location should be picked for those files which has CommonChar lines in them with unique second argument (pins or nails or xyz)....

Comment: @Heyya, yes it will. Whenever it creates a group dict (e.g. for ‘pins’), it stores the name of the file where it first found that group. Give it a try.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I am getting topic:data two times every time for some reason with your improved code except for fileLocation. With group_dict its little confusing to me. Did you cover all the three scenarios as I did with  this :     if parts[1] in mainDict:
        if parts[2] in mainDict[parts[1]]:
            mainDict[parts[1]][parts[2]].extend(['</br>']+parts[3:])
        else:
            mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]})
    else:
        mainDict[parts[1]]={}
        mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]})

Comment: @Heyya, it's probably best to shift these comments onto my answer instead of continuing on this question. I tried my code again and noticed that the `pprint` statement was inside the loop when it should be outside. So `main_dict` was getting printed when it was partly constructed and again after it was completed. I've fixed that, so maybe it's better now. I also split the data into two files and gave a detailed answer to your question about the if/else logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I've made a few changes to your code:

1. Open and read the file in a `with` clause, to guarantee it gest closed when done.
2. Split each item into meaningful variables, to make it easier to keep track of what's going on.
3. Used Python-style naming and punctuation instead of Matlab (`main_dict = {}` vs. `mainDict={}`) .
4. Used `setdefault` to make sure `main_dict` has an empty dict for each group, before assigning to it (this is generally less repetitive and easier to maintain than having separate branches to create an entry if it doesn't exist or update it if it does.)
5. Used `.extend` instead of `.append` to add more items to the payload list.

/tmp/data1.txt

```
CommonChar pins Category General
CommonChar pins Contact Mark
CommonChar pins Description This is a 
CommonChar pins Description secondLine
```

/tmp/data2.txt

```
CommonChar nails Category specific
CommonChar nails Contact John 
CommonChar nails Description This is a description
```

script.py (updated to scan multiple files listed in `files` variable)

```
import re, pprint

files = ['/tmp/data1.txt', '/tmp/data2.txt']

main_dict = {}
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, "r") as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
    items = re.findall("CommonChar.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
    for x in items:
        cc, group, topic, data = x.split(None, 3)
        data = data.split()
        group_dict = main_dict.setdefault(group, {'fileLocation': [filename]})
        if topic in group_dict:
            group_dict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
        else:
            group_dict[topic] = data

pprint.pprint(main_dict)
```

output

```
{'nails': {'Category': ['specific'],
           'Contact': ['John'],
           'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description'],
           'fileLocation': ['/tmp/data.txt']},
 'pins': {'Category': ['General'],
          'Contact': ['Mark'],
          'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', '</br>', 'secondLine'],
          'fileLocation': ['/tmp/data.txt']}}
```

By the way, if your code encounters an error, it should raise an exception, rather than calling `sys.exit()`, e.g., `raise ValueError("Bad value in file")`.

You asked in a comment on your question whether the code above is equivalent to your code as follows:

```
if parts[1] in mainDict: 
    if parts[2] in mainDict[parts[1]]: 
        mainDict[parts[1]][parts[2]].extend(['</br>']+parts[3:]) 
    else: 
        mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]}) 
else: 
    mainDict[parts[1]]={} 
    mainDict[parts[1]].update({parts[2]:parts[3:]})
```

It is, and here's a breakdown of how that works. First, the line `cc, group, topic, data = x.split(None, 3)` makes `group` equivalent to `parts[1]`, and `topic` equivalent to `parts[2]`. Then the next line makes `data` equivalent to `parts[3:]`. Making those substitutions gives the following:

```
if group in mainDict: 
    if topic in mainDict[group]: 
        mainDict[group][topic].extend(['</br>'] + data) 
    else: 
        mainDict[group].update({topic: data]}) 
else: 
    mainDict[group]={} 
    mainDict[group].update({topic: data]})
```

Next, we note that the code above is equivalent to:

```
# next line sets groupDict=mainDict[group], creating it if needed
groupDict = mainDict.setdefault(group, {})
if topic in groupDict:
    groupDict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
else:
    groupDict.update({topic: data]})
```

Finally, we note that it's possible to store the file name when first creating the groupDict, and that `groupDict.update({topic: data]})` is equivalent to `groupDict[topic] = data`. With those changes, we get:

```
groupDict = mainDict.setdefault(group, {'fileLocation': [filename]})
if topic in groupDict:
    groupDict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
else:
    groupDict[topic] = data
```

Other than spelling, that is the same as the last five lines of my solution:

```
group_dict = main_dict.setdefault(group, {'fileLocation': [filename]})
if topic in group_dict:
    group_dict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
else:
    group_dict[topic] = data
```

Comment: How can I capture the file location (/home/....) of where I find the CommonChar ?

Comment: I updated the code to store the filename when it first creates the `group_dict`. Note that if multiple files contain the same group name ('nails', 'pins', etc.), only the name of the first one will be stored.

Comment: If in the above code I want to make sure that fields "Category" and "Description" are must to be in the file. Then I am placing a code like this which is not working .

Comment: cc, group, topic, data = x.split(None, 3)
data = data.split()
 group_dict = mainDict.setdefault(group, {'fileLocation': [filePath]})
if topic in mustNeededTags: 
print("Min no of tags met, proceed....\n")               
 if topic in group_dict:
 group_dict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
       print("Warning: Multiple entries of utilName:tagName->%s:%s in file %s : Ignore if intentionally done" %  (group, topic,filePath))
                 else:
                     group_dict[topic] = data
             else: 
     print("Min no of tags not met\n")

Comment: I can't really tell from your comments what you are trying to achieve. You mention "Category" and "Description" in your comment, but your new code doesn't mention them, and just seems to require that `topic` is in `mustNeededTags`. I don't know what is in `mustNeededTags` or what you want to happen. You may do best to open a new question, spelling out what you are trying to do and showing your current code, with correct formatting.

Comment: I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779305/how-to-flag-if-a-dictionary-key-is-absent