# How to flag if a dictionary key is absent

Tags: python

I have files with CommonChar is some of them and my python code works on them to build a dictionary. While building there are some required keys which users might forget to put in. The code should be able to flag the file and the key which is missing.

The syntax for python code to work on is like this:

```
CommonChar pins Category General
CommonChar pins Contact Mark
CommonChar pins Description 1st line 
CommonChar pins Description 2nd line 
CommonChar nails Category specific
CommonChar nails Description 1st line
```

So for above example "Contact" is missing: 
CommonChar nails Contact Robert

I have a list for ex: mustNeededKeys=["Category", "Description", "Contact"]

```
mainDict={}
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for eachFile in fileList:
        #excluding file names ending in .swp , swo which are creatied temporarily when editing in vim
        if not eachFile.endswith(('.swp','.swo','~')):
            #print eachFile
            filePath= os.path.join(dirName,eachFile)
        #print filePath
            with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
                contents=fh.read()
            items=re.findall("CommonChar.*$",contents,re.MULTILINE)
            for x in items:
        cc, group, topic, data = x.split(None, 3)
                data = data.split()
                group_dict = mainDict.setdefault(group, {'fileLocation': [filePath]})                        
                if topic in group_dict:                 
                    group_dict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
                else:
                    group_dict[topic] = data
```

This above code does its job of building a dict like this:

```
{'pins': {'Category': ['General'], 'Contact': ['Mark'], 'Description': ['1st', 'line', '2nd', 'line'] } , 'nails':{'Category':['specific'], 'Description':['1st line']}
```

So when reading each file with CommonChar and building a group_dict , a way to check all the keys and compare it with mustNeededKeys and flag if not there and proceed if met.

Comment: "Must needed" -> "required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
# Setup mainDict (equivalent to code given above)
mainDict = {
    'nails': {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Description': ['1st', 'line'],
        'fileLocation': ['/some/path/nails.txt']
    },
    'pins': {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['1st', 'line', '</br>', '2nd', 'line'],
        'fileLocation': ['/some/path/pins.txt']
    }
}

# check for missing keys
mustNeededKeys = {"Category", "Description", "Contact"}
for group, group_dict in mainDict.items():
    missing_keys = mustNeededKeys - set(group_dict.keys())
    if missing_keys:
        missing_key_list = ','.join(missing_keys)
        print(
            'group "{}" ({}) is missing key(s): {}'
            .format(group, group_dict['fileLocation'][0], missing_key_list)
        )
# group "nails" (/some/path/nails.txt) is missing key(s): Contact
```

If you must check for missing keys immediately after processing each group, you could use the code below. This assumes that each group is stored as a contiguous collection of rows in a single file (i.e., not mixed with other groups in the same file or spread across different files).

```
from itertools import groupby

mainDict={}
mustNeededKeys = {"Category", "Description", "Contact"}
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for eachFile in fileList:
        # excluding file names ending in .swp , swo which are created 
        # temporarily when editing in vim
        if not eachFile.endswith(('.swp','.swo','~')):
            #print eachFile
            filePath = os.path.join(dirName,eachFile)
            #print filePath
            with open(filePath, "r") as fh:
                contents = fh.read()
            items = re.findall("CommonChar.*$", contents, re.MULTILINE)
            split_items = [line.split(None, 3) for line in items]
            # group the items by group name (element 1 in each row)
            for g, group_items in groupby(split_items, lambda row: row[1]):
                group_dict = {'fileLocation': [filePath]}
                # store all items in the current group
                for cc, group, topic, data in group_items:
                    data = data.split()
                    if topic in group_dict:
                        group_dict[topic].extend(['</br>'] + data)
                    else:
                        group_dict[topic] = data
                # check for missing keys
                missing_keys = mustNeededKeys - set(group_dict.keys())
                if missing_keys:
                    missing_key_list = ','.join(missing_keys)
                    print(
                        'group "{}" ({}) is missing key(s): {}'
                        .format(group, filePath, missing_key_list)
                    )
                # add group to mainDict
                mainDict[group] = group_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this wont work because its acting on mainDict and instead it should work on group_dict (which is a dictionary for every file). So I need a way where I have a list (mustNeededKeys ) and I check whether all the items in the list are there as keys in group_dict or not , if not then flag the item and file where its missing .....

Comment: Also I get this error:    missing_keys = mustNeededKeys - set(d.keys())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'set'

Comment: Can you look at my above two comments ?

Comment: I have updated the code to make it clearer that this is actually working with `group_dict`, and showing how to report the file name. If you want this to run while you create the original dictionaries, you should take all my code from `missing_keys = ...` to the end, and place that at the end of your `for eachfile ...` loop (at the same level of indentation as `if not eachfile...`). The error you are having is probably because you used square brackets when defining mustNeededKeys (which creates a list) instead of curly braces as shown in my code (which creates a set).

Comment: I am unable to place your code from missing_keys at "if not eachfile" indentation level because group_dict is not defined at that level. So I get this error : NameError: name group_dict is not defined. I would like to place it right after it goes through if else condition to build key value pairs and at the end when group_dict has all the needed key value pairs it should execute to compare against needed keys.So ideally I am thinking to place(missing_keys an onwards code) at "for x in items:"  indentation level  but it is complaining about group_dict not defined.

Comment: As currently written, your code allows for the possibility that one group could be spread across multiple files or that one file could hold multiple groups. Are both of these true? If so, then the only option is to check for the missing keys after constructing the whole mainDict. If each group can only appear in one file, but each file may have multiple groups, and you want to check for missing keys after each file, then you will need more complex code, to create something like mainDict for each file, check for missing keys, then merge that with mainDict.

Comment: On the other hand, if each file can only hold one group and each group can only appear in each file, then this can all be simplified a lot. So to answer your question I would need to know (1) can each group appear in multiple files, (2) can each file hold multiple groups, (3) is it important to check for missing keys after processing each file, and (4) are you hoping to check for missing keys after each group?

Comment: One group will be contained in one file, there might be a possibility to have multiple groups in a single file. But one group wont be distributed in multiple files. So to answer your question 1. No 2. Maybe 3. Since the assumption is each group will be in a single file so while key pairs are made for each group it would be easier to verify then and there whether required keys are met if not flag. 4. yes  Note: Right now I have one unique group for every file which I would like to flag missing keys for but in future I might have one file with multiple groups .

Comment: When there are multiple groups in the same file, can they be interleaved (some rows from one group then some rows from another group, then more rows from the first group), or will they always be clustered separately (all rows from the first group, then all rows from the second, then the third, etc.)? I'm trying to figure out how you will know when each group has been completely read in so you can check it for missing keys.

Comment: When there are multiple groups in the same file then all the groups will be clustered together as you said (all rows from the first group, then all rows from the second, then the third, etc)

Comment: I added some more code to do the check right after each group is processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''CommonChar pins Category General
CommonChar pins Contact Mark
CommonChar pins Description 1st line
CommonChar pins Description 2nd line
CommonChar nails Category specific
CommonChar nails Description 1st line'''

from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

required_keys = ["Category", "Description", "Contact"]

d = defaultdict(dict)
for line in data.splitlines():
    line = line.split()
    if line[2] == 'Description':
        if line[2] not in d[line[1]]:
            d[line[1]][line[2]] = []
        d[line[1]][line[2]].extend(line[3:])
    else:
        d[line[1]][line[2]] = [line[3]]

pprint(dict(d))
print('*' * 80)

# find missing keys
for k in d.keys():
    for missing_key in set(d[k].keys()) ^ set(required_keys):
        print('Key "{}" is missing "{}"!'.format(k, missing_key))
```

Prints:

```
{'nails': {'Category': ['specific'], 'Description': ['1st', 'line']},
 'pins': {'Category': ['General'],
          'Contact': ['Mark'],
          'Description': ['1st', 'line', '2nd', 'line']}}
********************************************************************************
Key "nails" is missing "Contact"!
```

Comment: Can you add the modification I am looking for in my current code instead ?

Comment: @Heyya your dict is the same as mine, so just use the part where I'm searching for missing keys.

Comment: Is your dict similar to mine (group_dict or mainDict??)Will it report the file as well when reports whats missing ?

Comment: @Heyya You need to integrate and adapt the code into your program yourself.

Comment: @Heyya The last three lines of this code would come after your code. Just run your code, then set `d = mainDict` and `required_keys = mustNeededKeys` and then the last three lines of this answer should report your missing keys.